# How can I remove "Column -1" from my DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I'm dynamically creating the `columns` and rows of my `DGV`, and then populating the `cells` with the appropriate values.

Even though at present the contents are too large for the `DataGridView` (I set `ScrollBars` to `None`), my first column is offset to the right, with a black strip there where `column` 0 should be. What property removes this intruder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set property `RowHeaderVisible` in `False`

```
yourDgv.RowHeadersVisible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the DataGridView property RowHeadersVisible to false.